# Selecting IntSlider widget by running code in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

In Jupyter Lab when the ipywidgets.IntSlider object is selected I can use the arrow keys to change its value interactively. Is it possible to select the IntSlider widget (or any widget) by running some code so that I don't have to click on it to be able to interact with it? Please see sample code below.

Use-case: I'm using some functionalities to set the value of an IntSlider. It would be nice to be able to interact with it using the arrow keys right after the value change without having to click on it.

```
import ipywidgets as w
w_int = w.IntSlider(
    value=7,
    min=0,
    max=10,
)
display(w_int)
# How can I select widget w_int at this point?
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Unfortunately I don't think is currently possible.

The technical limitation is that there can be arbitrary number of views of the same widget displayed. So you could easily do:

```py
display(w_int)
display(w_int)
display(w_int)
```

in which case there is no obvious way of ipywidgets to know which one you want to focus on.